# pd.DataFrame.update() doesn't carry over types. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a dataframe `df`. Two of its columns (`'neighborhood'` and `'price'`) contain strings. Each string in these two columns contain a number.

My goal is to create two lists containing only the numbers in the strings, and then overwrite the old columns in `df` with the new lists, in such a way that pandas' .corr() will be able to recognize and operate on them.

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Import data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep='|')

# Clean data (throw away room_id, remove html from neighborhood, make price float )
df = df.drop('room_id', 1)
neighborhood = np.array([float(n[3:-4]) for n in df['neighborhood']]).astype(np.float64)
price = np.array([float(p[7:-1]) for p in df['price']]).astype(np.float64)
df_updates = pd.DataFrame({'neighborhood' : neighborhood, 'price' : price})
df.update(df_updates)

# Print first row of dataframe and the output of df.corr()
print(df.iloc[0])
print(df.corr())

# Print types
print(type(neighborhood[0]))
print(type(price[0]))
print(type(df['neighborhood'][0]))
print(type(df['price'][0]))
```

As seen below, .corr() doesn't recognize the new `'neighborhood'` and `'price'` columns as things it can operate on.

```
Out []: 

room_type               Entire home/apt
neighborhood                          5
reviews                               0
satisfaction                          0
acc.                                  6
bedrooms                              3
price                                80
Name: 0, dtype: object

                      reviews               satisfaction  acc.      bedrooms
reviews               1.000000              0.520951     -0.037194 -0.064366
overall_satisfaction  0.520951              1.000000     -0.019771 -0.052900
accommodates         -0.037194             -0.019771      1.000000  0.720229
bedrooms             -0.064366             -0.052900      0.720229  1.000000

<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I suspect the above happens because the entries of `'neighborhood'` and `'price'` are simple floats (instead of np.float64's) in the dataframe, even though the corresponding ndarrays contained np.float64's when being passed through .update.

**Q:** Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: what are the original dtypes of `df`? can you try `print(df.dtypes)`. There may be a "funky" value in the column throwing it off

Comment: @MattR You're right! Both `price` and `neighborhood` are `object`! What to do though?

Comment: the simple answer: find the funky values, haha. You can try using [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to filter out what might be causing it or some other way.

Comment: @MattR I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MattR for giving the right hint! As seen with `df.dtypes`, the two problematic columns where `objects`, and .corr() can't handle that. The solution (as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648923/5748367)) is to do the following after defining a list `prob_cols` containing the names of the problematic columns:

```
df[prob_cols] = df[prob_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```